# In Angular 2 how to fill a span when I click a div and change the text above when the span/p is full?

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I'm new in this community and I have a basic english, but I hope to make me understand. I just started studying Angular 2 and my question is this:

I have created a keyboard and above there are 4 span each of which must contain a digit that will be clicked on the keyboard. Each time one of these keys is pressed (each key is a div) I would like that number to be displayed in one of these span, but I do not know how to do it. Also after pressing 4 numbers (and then filling the span) I would like the text above the span changes to another.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid fixed-heading">
   <div class="back-button">
     <img src="/assets/images/icon_arrow_left.png" (click)="back()" />
   </div>
   <app-main-app-header [heading]="'SETTINGS.SECURITY.PIN.HEADING'">{{"SETTINGS.SECURITY.PIN.HEADING"|translate}}</app-main-app-header>
</div>

<div class="container-fluid component">

  <div class="row pin text-center">

    <div>
      <span>Here I would like to have the text</span>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span></span>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span></span>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span></span>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-3">
        <span></span>
        <div class="line"></div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>1</span>
      <p>&nbsp;</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>2</span>
      <p>ABC</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 no-border-right cursor-pointer">
      <span>3</span>
      <p>DEF</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>4</span>
      <p>GHI</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>5</span>
      <p>JKL</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 no-border-right cursor-pointer">
      <span>6</span>
      <p>MNO</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row text-center">
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>7</span>
      <p>PQRS</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>8</span>
      <p>TUV</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 no-border-right cursor-pointer">
      <span>9</span>
      <p>WXYZ</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row text-center" id="no-border">
    <div class="col-xs-4 bg-color cursor-pointer">
      <span>&emsp;&ensp;&ensp;.</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-4 cursor-pointer">
      <span>0</span>
    </div>
     <div class="col-xs-4 no-border-right bg-color cursor-pointer">
      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-sign"></span>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.fixed-heading{
  left: 0;           /* Left edge at left for now */
  right: 0;          /* Right edge at right for now, so full width */
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 375px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 25;
  border-bottom: 1px inset seashell;
}

.back-button{
  cursor:pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 9px;
}

.pin{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  height: 300px;
}

.row{
  border-bottom: 1px inset;
  padding-bottom: -2px;
  font-size: xx-large;
}

.row.pin{
  border-bottom: none;
  border-right: none;
  font-size: small;
  padding: 80px;
}

p{
  font-size: small;
  margin-top: -8px;
}

.col-xs-4{
  border-right: 1px inset;
}

#no-border{
  border-bottom: none;
}

.no-border-right{
  border-right: none;
}

.bg-color{
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
}

.line{
  border: 2px solid grey;
  width: 25px;
}

.row.pin span{
  margin-left: 8px;
}

.glyphicon.glyphicon-remove-sign{
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7 and Angular 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to create something like a PIN code input. If that's correct, I think the best approach would have been to use keyboard input, and leveraging angular's built-in functionality described [here](https://angular.io/guide/user-input).

However, to answer your question, one approach would be the following:

```
// In your component

public textThatChanges = 'previous text';
public input: string = '';

click(numberClicked: string) {
  if (this.input.length < 4) {
    this.input += numberClicked;
  }
  else if (this.input.length === 4) {
    this.textThatChanges = 'new text';
  }
}

// In the template
<!-- This is the span that changes after 4 clicks -->
<span>{{ textThatChanges }}</span>

<!-- As requested - 4 different elements, each displaying 1 digit -->
<span>{{ input.charAt(0) }}</span>
<span>{{ input.charAt(1) }}</span>
<span>{{ input.charAt(2) }}</span>
<span>{{ input.charAt(3) }}</span>

<!-- Do the following for each of the divs that can be clicked -->
<div (click)="click('1')"><span>1</span></div>
<div (click)="click('2')"><span>2</span></div>
```

Comment: Your method is almost correct, but if you look at the html I did when I click a number, that number goes to all 4 spans, while I would like to go first on the first, second time on the second and so on

Comment: I updated the answer, please check if this does what you need.